# NSMutableAttributedString - NSForegroundColorAttributeName

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I am trying to set the color of all the ranges in my array but I am getting this error. I don't understand why. the ranges are all valid. I even tried manually inserting a range to test it. Thank You.

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0

```
NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:tv.text];

for (NSString * s in array) {
        [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSRangeFromString(s)];
}

CATextLayer *textlayer = [[CATextLayer alloc]init];
textlayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:textlayer];
textlayer.string = @"aString"; //works
textlayer.string = string; //does not work
tv.text = @"";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is the code example the exact same code as you are trying to build? Im quite sure `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is only available in Mac OS X SDK and iOS 6.0 and later so the example code should not even compile.

What you want instead is probably `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` and pass a `CGColorRef` instead of a `NSColor`.

```
[string addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
               value:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor
               range:NSRangeFromString(s)];
```

But im not sure if this really is the cause of the invalid context error.

Comment: ERROR: it says use of undeclared identifier "kCTForegroundColorAttributeName"... Framework???

Comment: Got it i forgot core text. Thanks

Comment: Nice. So the invalid context error went away? but did it compile when you used `NSForegroundColorAttributeNameis`? hmm

Comment: FYI, `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is available since iOS 6.0, just so no one gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

Your context is wrong, not your range. You're trying to set the color of something that doesn't have a color.

Comment: what does that mean in this case. do you have a solution.